# Error Handling (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, exception, error-handling

Fairly easy question, but I was basically given code to debug and I've fixed all errors but one. When trying to make the program more friendly and include error handling, I found that the error message is thrown even if the condition is satisfied (that is, the number in the array that a user searches for actually exists within the array). Not looking for a direct answer, just a hint. I've tried using combinations of if/else as well as moving around curly braces.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer to find: ");

    try {
        int number = input.nextInt();
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, number);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
               if ( array[i] == number )
                   System.out.println("Found " + number + " at index " + index++);
       }
            System.out.printf("Your number was not found within the array.");
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.printf("Sorry, but it looks like you entered something other than an integer. Please try again.");   
    }
}
```

Console output example:

```
Enter an integer to find: -9
```

> Found -9 at index 0
>   
>  Your number was not found within the array.

Comment: What do you think happens when the first entry in `array` isn't tne correct number?

Comment: Just print the error message in your else clause. Don't throw an exception.

Comment: @tkausl Hmm, so it's only checking the array for the first number?

Comment: @Jecoms this helped but the message is repeated many times.

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop anyway? You're already getting the index if it exists using the binary search array function. if `index` is -1, then your number wasn't found.

Comment: @Jecoms I'm not sure I understand the loop, but I do think I've improved the code to get a better result from the console. I only get the error message once now, since I think it's not checking every index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)) will return the index if it finds the value, otherwise it will return -1.

If `index == -1`, you can print the "not found message" without entering the loop at all.

Otherwise, if `index > 0`, then you can enter the loop and iterate over the array to find each index where the value is a match.

This is required if you want a message for multiple matches as binarySearch will just return the the first index the value was found at.

As an aside, binarySearch requires the array to be sorted first, otherwise the results will be undefined. I don't know if this is a problem as array is declared outside of the example.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an integer to find: ");

try {
    int number = input.nextInt();
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, number);

    if (index > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           if ( array[i] == number ) {
               System.out.println("Found " + number + " at index " + i);
           }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Sorry, your number wasn't found.");   
    }
}
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.printf("Sorry, but it looks like you entered something other than an integer. Please try again.");  
}
```

Comment: Yes, besides the array saying that the value at index[0

Comment: Besides the array saying that the value at index[0] wasn't found, yes that's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @Walby. Ah. So you want multiple messages if the number appears more than once.

Comment: @Walby The index in the message was referencing the binary search index. It should actually be printing out the current value of `i` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The condition inside the loop is wrong. If the first element of the array isn't the value you were looking for, it immediately terminates. The error handling must be after the loop. Try this:

```
 boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ( array[i] == number ){
            System.out.println("Found " + number + " at index " + index++);
            found = true;}
    }
    if(!found)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your number was not found within the array.");
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code:
*"Your number was not found within the array."* will always be printed unless there is an exception caught by catch block
also one interesting thing about binary search is :
 if an element is not present in the array, it returns **negative of the *probable position*** if the searched element "would have been" present.
**Example** : in this program, if you search for 9,it will return -3
if you search for 65,it will return -6

This will work correctly:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class debug {
public static void main(String...args){

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer to find: ");
        int i, array[]={-9,8,14,56,64};
        try {
            int number = input.nextInt();
            int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, number);

            if(index>=0)
            System.out.println("Found " + number + " using binary search at index " + index);
            else
                System.out.println("Not Found !! index returned by binary search is : "+index);

            boolean flag=false;
            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                   if ( array[i] == number ){
                       flag=true;
                       break;
                   }
           }
            if(flag)
                System.out.println("Found " + number + " using for loop at index " + i);
            else
          System.out.printf("Your number was not found within the array.");
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.printf("Sorry, but it looks like you entered something other than an integer. Please try again.");   
        }
    }

}
```